# Using Both AND and OR in IF Statement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm working on a Google Spreadsheet adding scripts (Not formulas) and I am stuck on a problem.

I need to find a way to use something like this:

```
If (Product == "Shampoo" && (Box == "15" OR Box == "17"))
{
  //Do Something...
}
```

Basically IF the product is a shampoo and the box it belongs to is either 15 or 17 then do something. I know doing a `If (Product == "Shampoo" && Box == "15" OR Box == "17")` will produce unexpected or bad results. How do we go about using an OR with AND in google scripting?

From what I understand Google Scripts are based on Javascript but I can't seem to find help posts online or here in SO, all I get are solutions in formula not script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you looking for is the [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) of the two operators [logical AND `&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) and [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()).

Part of the table:

```
Precedence  Operator type  Associativity    Individual operators
----------  -------------  ---------------  --------------------
       6    Logical AND    left-to-right    … && …
       5    Logical OR     left-to-right    … || …
```

You see a higher operator precendece of logical AND over logical OR. That means you need some parenthesis for the OR statement.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. Followup Question: Is the statement above `If (Product == "Shampoo" && (Box == "15" OR Box == "17"))` already correct?

Comment: @NinaScholz: On Google Apps Script that statement doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

First a note about the OP code

JavaScript methods are case sensitive.

Instead of `IF` the correct syntax is `if`. By the other hand the Logical OR operator is `||`.

Considering the above, the OP code could be replaced by

```
if(Product == "Shampoo" && (Box == "15" || Box == "17"))
{
  //Do Something...
}
```

and

```
if(Product == "Shampoo" && Box == "15" || Box == "17")
```

Regarding the question, if `(Product == "Shampoo" && Box == "15" || Box == "17")` returns unexpected or bad results, this could be hard to read and lead to confusions for humans but JavaScript have very specific rules regarding how operations should be made by the engine, in this case Rhino which is used by Google Apps Script.

As was mentioned in [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48170889/1595451) in this case the rule is called [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) but in order to make the code easier to read and to prevent confusions a good practice is to enclose each comparison in parenthesis.

Considering that the Logical AND has a higher precedence than Logical OR

```
(Product == "Shampoo" && Box == "15" || Box == "17")
```

is the same as

```
((Product == "Shampoo" && Box == "15") || Box == "17")
```

References

- [if..else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)
- [Logical OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_())

Comment: i don't find it a good practice to add superfluous brackes to do readers a favor. for any other operators, like addition or multiplication, no one would add some parenthesis for it, because all can read it without. why not assume it for boolean operators?

Comment: @NinaScholz You are right, actually that what I think to say but I didn't. My bad. I will fix this later, hopefully this night.